# Anyone know the full signature for Facebook's PRIVATE auth.login API method

Tags: facebook-authentication, facebook-rest-api

I am working on a white listed app that is allowed to called the private auth.login api. Because the api is a **private** one the standard Facebook docs at developers.facebook.com don't help.

There was a draft security bulletin a few months back that said we would need to start passing a unique machine id. I am retreiving this from the rest api but am getting "incorrect signature" errors when passing it back up.

Anyone else now passing up machine_id?

Comment: I dont think there are many app developers here on s/o that have access to the private api.  Most all of us are using the public one.  You should contact Facebook directly, rather than posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, but the machine id can be whatever you want, then the signature is generated based on machine_id and others param ;)